# Asynchronous programming model and application scale

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm looking to better understand how the asynchronous programming model. Let's assume that the web service called in the following takes 1 second to return:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://service.com");

    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Is it correct to say that when `await` is used with the asynchronous method, the current thread is yielded back to the threadpool for other work? Does using the asynchronous model save 1 second of work per request since that thread isn't sitting around waiting for the web service to respond?

Comment: Define `saving 1 second of work`. Is each request exactly one second? Multithreading never saves you work. The same work is always going to be performed. However, it can save you time.

Comment: In general, it means the thread can be used for other work. The asynchronous `GetStringAsync` method uses asynchronous I/O callbacks, so it doesn't even need to use new threads. In other words, in an I/O bound application, having more threads doesn't help at all. Calling `AccessTheWebAsync` asynchronously 100 times will mean it will take more or less one second, rather than 100 seconds if done synchronously in one thread.

Comment: @Gusdor By savings, I mean that a thread isn't spending some amount of time not doing useful work because it is waiting for something to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that when await is used with the asynchronous method, the current thread is yielded back to the threadpool for other work?

Yes.

> Does using the asynchronous model save 1 second of work per request since that thread isn't sitting around waiting for the web service to respond?

It frees up a thread for that second that would have otherwise been blocking.

This makes no difference from the perspective of a single request; the request still has to wait for the operation to complete, and the request doesn't care whether it waits synchronously (blocks) or waits asynchronously (await). But it makes a difference from the perspective of the server application as a whole: fewer threads are necessary to handle larger number of requests.

Answer (score 2):

The calling thread returns immediately when an `await` statement is called. If you are on a context thread (a UI or ASP.net thread) then the behavior is different but the result is largely the same.

The thread will only return to the pool if no other code follows and the vcalling thread is actually a threadpool thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using `async` and `await` calls in WebApi. What happens is that when you reach the `await` statement, the control is given to the calling method unitl the task(in this case `client.GetStringAsync("http://service.com")`) is complete. This is a problem, because the calling method **will** try to return a value, regardless of the completion of the task and if the task is **not** complete you will get an exception, something like

> A return statement was called while an async task was still in progress

In your case, since you have only 1 operation, which is getting the content from another site, you do not need it to be async. If you were getting content from 2 or more separate sites, then it would make sense to use async calls.